# Add both `s` and `S` to ace-window's dispatch list

Tags: key-bindings

I've created two functions, `scroll-window-up` and `scroll-window-down`, and want to add these to ace-window's dispatch list:

```
(add-to-list 'aw-dispatch-alist
             '(?S gpolonkai/scroll-window-down " Scroll window down"))
(add-to-list 'aw-dispatch-alist
             '(?s gpolonkai/scroll-window-up " Scroll window up"))
```

When I press `s` in dispatch time, the selected window scrolls up,but for `S` it says <s>there is no such candidate</s>. I remember it worked on my other machine, so there may be some differences in how the two OS handles keys. If I'm right, is there a more reliable way to distinguish between upper and lower case characters? If not, can I specify C-s or M-s where it needs a character?

**Edit**: it seems I messed up a bit… the error message I get when pressing `S` is:

```
Args out of range: "S", 0, 5
```

Comment: Which two OS's are you dealing with? Upper and lower case letters work for me.

Comment: Windows and Fedora Linux. And it turns out the same problem exists on my Android phone with Termux.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why `S` might not be working for you, but you can use a modifier key.

Try this: invoke ace-window, and hit for example `C-s` at the dispatch prompt. The error message actually tells you what character was sent, e.g.

```
No such candidate, 19
```

You can use that to add `C-s` to your dispatch list:

```
(add-to-list 'aw-dispatch-alist '(19 some-command " Do Something"))
```

Comment: You may be able to get `S` working the same way, i.e. use the number reported in the "no such candidate" message you are seeing to define the dispatch command.

Comment: Thanks for the `C-s` workaround! It works fine, although I hope I will get an answer less hacky. I corrected my question as it seems I messed it up a bit. Sorry about that.